# Adonis make:model gerando model com nome diferente

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, adonisjs

Executei o comando adonis

> make:model CaredPerson -mc

para que fossem criados o controller e a migration juntos. Após executar o comando, tentei alterar o nome do model, migration e controller para CaredPeople, porém, ao fazer o relacionamento belongsToMany('App/Models/CaredPeople') do adonis referenciando o model, as chaves buscadas na tabela pivot e o nome da tabela pivot ficam com o nome "person" e não "people", tentei passar o das chaves e da tabela porém não funcionou...
Após isso, tentei deletar o model, o controller e a migration e então executar novamente o comando de criação com o nome correto:

> make:model CaredPeople -mc

porém ao ser executado, o arquivo criado para todos os três vem com a palavra "person", por exemplo, model: CaredPerson; controller: CaredPersonController; migration: cared_person; mesmo que eu tenha executado o comando passando um nome diferente.

Tentei baixar o projeto em outra maquina e executar o comando, na esperança de ser algum cache porêm acontece o mesmo... 
Alguém tem uma ideia de como solucionar?

Answer (score 1):

Não há como "resolver" isso, já que não se trata de um erro, e sim de uma convenção.

Assim como outros frameworks do tipo, como Ruby on Rails ou Laravel, o AdonisJs tem uma série de convenções em relação a como o seu código deve ser feito. Entre elas, há uma convenção que define as regras de nomenclatura para os *models* e nome de tabelas.

De acordo com a convenção do Adonis, os *models* devem sempre estar no singular (e em `PascalCase`), enquanto as tabelas devem ser nomeadas no plural (e em `snake_case`).

Desse modo, não há nada de errado. Do inglês, `Person` é o singular de `People`, que é o plural. Assim, quando você rodar o comando, o Adonis criará um *model* no singular (`Person`) e as tabelas (nas *migrations*) usando o plural (`people`).

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se contornar essa convenção de nomenclatura utilizada pelo Adonis informando no Model o nome da tabela a ser utilizada na migration.

```
    class User extends Model {
  static get table () {
    return 'my_users'
  }
}
```

[Referencia Manual Adonis 4.1](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_convention_over_configuration)

Comment: Ao meu ver esta resposta solucionará o seu problema.